# Is it able to directly open a wallet using web3Modal 3?

Tags: javascript, wallet-connect, web3modal

[current comp: open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x16PU.png)

The current open() func does have some useful options, while I want to realize a more direct way to open one wallet. For example:

```
open({
  specificWallet:'metamask'
})
```

or

```
//metamask
open({
  specificWalletId:'c57ca95b47569778a828d19178114f4db188b89b763c899ba0be274e97267d96'
})
```

**Just without choosing which wallet to connect.**

Is it possible? Or does it have a simple way to realize this?

I've tried using js's document.getElement to call the current w3mButton to be ".click()"ed, while it seems no use.
I've also thought about compiling source code, exporting a simple  or something, but I give it up when I saw how complicated is the w3m's framework.